# Listar por orden de fecha en angular 7 con material, firebase como gestor

Tags: firebase, angular7

busco una forma para listar por orden de fecha los comentarios de mi aplicación, he buscado y no se como hacerlo en angular 7, quisiera que me ayudaran, gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta el momento este es mi codigo, funciona pero me lista desordenandamente. yo quiero listar por orden de fechas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Debes poner siempre tu código en formato texto y no como imagen para que lo podamos copiar, reproducir tu problemática y poder ayudarte. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div  *ngFor="let com of list" class="dividir">
  <div style="color:blue" (click)="onEdit(com)">{{com.email}}</div>
  <p (click)="onEdit(com)">{{com.fecha}}</p>
  <p (click)="onEdit(com)">{{com.informacion}}</p>
  <div><a class=" btn text-danger"(click)="onDelete(com.id)">Eliminar<i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></div>
  <!-- <div><a class=" btn text-danger"   (click)="onDelete(com.id)">Elimminar<i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></div>-->
  <mat-divider> </mat-divider> 
</div>

<!--  
<div class="col-md-12">

      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="table-active">
          <th>email</th>
          <th>informacion</th>
         <th></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let com of list">
            <td style="color:rgba(0, 51, 128, 0.397);" (click)="onEdit(com)">{{com.email}}</td>
            <td style="color:rgba(0, 70, 128, 0.466);" (click)="onEdit(com)">{{com.informacion}}</td>
            <td><a class=" btn text-danger"   (click)="onDelete(com.id)">Elimminar<i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>


    </div>

  -->
```

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import {ComentarioService} from 'src/app/servicio/comentario.service';
import {Comentario} from 'src/app/modelos/comentario.model';





@Component({
  selector: 'app-comentario-list',
  templateUrl: './comentario-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comentario-list.component.css']
})
export class ComentarioListComponent implements OnInit {
  list:Comentario[];
  constructor(private service: ComentarioService,
    private firestore: AngularFirestore,
    private toastr:ToastrService) { }



  ngOnInit() {

    this.service.getComentario().subscribe(actionArray => {
      this.list = actionArray.map(item => {
        return {
          id: item.payload.doc.id,
          ...item.payload.doc.data()
        } as Comentario;
      })
    });
  }

  onEdit(com:Comentario) {
    this.service.formData = Object.assign({}, com);
  }

  onDelete(id: string) {
    if (confirm("¿Estás seguro de eliminar este registro?")) {
      this.firestore.doc('comments/' + id).delete();
      this.toastr.warning('Se elimino...','Registro del comentario...');
    }
  }
}

Servicio
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Comentario} from '../modelos/comentario.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ComentarioService {
  formData: Comentario;

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

  getComentario() {
    return this.firestore.collection('comments').snapshotChanges();
  }
}
```